# C++ - member variable aggregate initialization

Tags: c++

In the following code:

```
class Class
{
private:
LUID luid;

public:
Class()
{
luid = { 0, 0}; // A. Does not compile
LUID test = {0, 0}; // B. Compiles
test = {1,1}; // C. Does not compile
}
```

Why are A and C not right, but B is fine?

The error I get for A and C is:

error C2059: syntax error :
 '{'

error C2143: syntax error :
 missing ';' before '{'

error C2143: syntax error :
 missing ';' before '}'

I think it has to do with the C++ version, although I am not sure which version this is using besides it not being very new.

Comment: Well then time to find out what compiler you are using (name, version number, etc.)?

Comment: How is `LUID` defined?  Do you have C++11 or higher turned on?

Comment: @UnholySheep The only common C++ compiler that outputs errors in that format is MS VC++.

Answer (score 3):

Statement `LUID test = {0, 0}` is an *initialization* of a local variable using an initialization list; this is valid, as it is used in the course of a variable definition. `test = {0, 0}`, in contrast, is an *assignment*, as `test` is defined elsewhere. Assigning initializer lists is supported only in particular cases (e.g. when assigning to a scalar or to a particular sort of class type (cf., for example, [braced-init-list assignment](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ass#9)).

Other cases, like, for example, arrays, cannot be assigned but just initialized:

```
typedef int LUID[2];

int main(){

    LUID t = { 10, 20 }; // compiles
    // t = { 10, 20};     // does not compile, since an array is not assignable

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: That doesn’t explain why it was giving a *syntax* error. It’s valid syntax even if it isn’t valid to do it for the `LUID` class.